# Who composed this common melody for Shema' in the Musaf Kedushah (n. Ashkenaz)?

Tags: music, nusach-ashkenaz, authorship, kedusha-prayer

Who composed the melody for the Hu Elokeinu part of the Shema' section of Kedushah recited at Musaf on Shabbath and Yom Tov, which is demonstrated [in this recording](https://youtu.be/mg_48J9GIVc?t=6m19s) (at about the 6:19 mark)?

Comment: Zamru Lo: The Next Generation (Shiovitz) says "Folk Tune" (Vol. I, p. 321).  That's not particularly helpful, I know, but it's at least evidence that the identity of the composer is not well-known.

Comment: @menachem - While the singer in the video tutorial uses the tune only for the Hu Elokeinu part of the Shema' section, and while I will concede that it is certainly very likely that it is intended for that part and not the Shema' Yisrael line itself, in many, many cases the Shema' Yisrael line is sung to that tune as well.